# Grunt undo my changements when I restart it

Tags: gruntjs

I have a problem with grunt... I edit my file and save it but when I restart grunt, grunt undo the changements I just did.

Does someone know the resolution of this problem?

Comment: If you don't share code (your Gruntfile.js) and specifics about what you're doing, we won't be able to answer this exactly. A hunch tells me you're editing the resulting output of a grunt task, rather than the source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

Apparently, the cause of my problem was that my gruntfile.js was corrupted... :/